# Regex match strings and not docstings or comment strings

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext

I am trying to match valid strings in a bunch of code e.g.:
`myvar = "abc"`->match 'abc'.
`dict['key'] = 'value'` -> match 'key' and 'value' separately.
`default_val = ''` -> match '' (empty string).

However I don't want it to match docstrings or strings inside comments, e.g.

```
"""
some doc string
with some random 'string'
"""
```

`#this comment contains "a string"`
both of these should not match anything.

I use tab indentation as well so that may need to be included in the regex and i only want the actual string to be returned as a match.

Currently I have managed to get to this: `^\t*(?!#).+(?:[^\"\']{2,})[\"\'].*[\"\']$` which doesn't work and probably never will how I'm wanting it.

example of methods
find first case of " or ' in line:
if "" or '' is next in line then skip checking to after next instance of """ or '''
else match to next case of " or ' if looking back on same line has no #

Comment: How can you distinguish doc-strings from regular triple-quoted strings

Comment: which tool/language are you using?

Comment: @mousetail 3 quotes or double quotes are used for docstrings and i only use it for that.

Comment: @Mark I'm using SublimeText (latest) which I think uses the same regex version as Python3

Comment: @ScottPaterson Very unlikely to use a similar regex framework, there are no versions. Every program does things completely different

Comment: @ScottPaterson I might be wrong but I think you might need something more sophisticated than just regex for this, as you're going to have to keep track of when you're inside brackets and when not

Comment: Do you want a SublimeText regex or can you use code too? If the latter is possible, are you using Python or another language? What is the original goal?

Comment: @Mark do brackets matter? im only looking for strings no matter where they are except comments or docstrings.

Comment: @InSync I am replacing all stings in my code with a table the loading that table as a variable so i can change them of the fly for multiple language. The code is 10k lines so there's a lot to filter out. i am using `[\"\'].*[\"\']` for now which works but also shows docstrings and comments which makes it harder to find any i have missed. `(?![\"]{3}.*[\"]{3})[\"\']+?[^\"\n]{2}.*[\"\']+?` almost works to eliminate docstrings but matches too much for `x["test"] = "test". I need it to be for Sublime as this is for finding only.

Comment: @ScottPaterson think about something like `""" 'hello world' """"  "hi" """ hello again""""` - how would you be able to tell that "hi" isn't within a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Sublime Text, you'll find that the syntax highlighting has already done the work of processing the file using regular expressions to determine where the strings are, and it differentiates them from docstrings by applying a different "scope" to them.

So, to get all the strings in the currently open file:

- go to the View menu -> Show Console.
- paste/type in `view.sel().clear(); view.sel().add_all(view.find_by_selector("string"))`
- press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- close the Console panel with <kbd>Esc</kbd>

All the strings are selected, ready for copy and pasting. (Pasting multiple selections in to a separate document for example will have one selection per line.)

If you want those strings without the quotation marks, simply change the scope selector used:

`view.sel().add_all(view.find_by_selector("string - punctuation.definition.string"))`

You can see the scope of any text immediately to the right of the caret by going to the Tools menu -> Developer -> Show Scope Name.
You can learn more about scope selectors at http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selectors.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to match the strings you want to discard.

- Docstring `\"\"\"(?:.|\s)*\"\"\"`
- Comment `^#.*$`

Then, finally, you can try and match the string you want to keep.

- `\"([^\"]*)\"`

You can used named capture groups to distinguish between matches to discard and matches to keep. Put all together, the regex is `(?P<discard>\"\"\"(?:.|\s)*\"\"\"|^#.*$)|\"(?P<keep>[^\"]*)\"`.

I gave [a similar answer for PCRE in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76915546/260584).